# How to force a hvFloat to be "Here"

Tags: floats, positioning, rotating

A want to rotate my table but not on a newpage that is why i use hvFloat instead of sidewaystable. But with this one i have an other issue. The table won't get under the title. Is there someone who has an idea to force this table to be under the section title?

[image]

Here is a minimal code with my issue :

```
\documentclass[frenchb,11pt,a4paper]{report}       
\usepackage [frenchb]{babel}                       
\usepackage [ansinew]{inputenc}                
\usepackage [T1]{fontenc}                          

\usepackage{hvfloat}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}
\section{Title} 
    \hvFloat[floatPos=!h,rotAngle=90,capPos=t,capVPos=c,capWidth=w,floatCapSep=10]{table}{
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
        \begin{scriptsize}
        \begin{tabular}{rrr}
        \toprule
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        \midrule
            (As)& 16,00 & 300,00 \\
            (Sb)& 10,87 & <5,00\\
            (Ba)& 100,00 & 42,00 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \end{scriptsize}}
        {Caption}{tab:test}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the [package documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hvfloat) you will find (section 8):

> ### The `nonfloat` Option
>
> Sometimes it is better to put a "float" in a specific position of the
>   page. This is possible with the `nonfloat` package and the option
>   `nonFloat=true`.

Comment: Doh! I had it before my eyes and didn't saw it... Thanks a lot :-/
And sorry to ask something that was clearly written...